# Should we include a potential predictor into a prediction model if its P value is >0.05 but it improves AUC and/or model fit?

Tags: r, logistic, predictive-models

I am in the process of finalizing my logistic prediction model. However, I am not sure whether to include some specific predictors. I read about many papers and they left predictors in the final prediction model if their p-values are below 0.05. However, what should I do if my predictor candidate has a p-value > 0.05 (e.g., 0.06) when added to the model but it improves the model fit and AUC?

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion of predictors because of "statistical significance" is an invalid approach, and changes in c-index (concordance probability; AUROC) is a poor choice of measures because of lack of sensitivity/statistical power.  Pre-specification of models is a better idea.  As for indexes of predictive performance look at [this](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).

Comment: Can you pls explain why the inclusion of predictors based on "p-value" is not a valid approach? I actually saw many studies using stepwise selection to build the final prediction model (i.e. p<0.05 will be retained in the final model).